# Close long running task in CoroutineScope Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have outdated update system in my app, it is outdated because use AsyncTask. In ViewModel the task is called, and then start download apk file. While app download file function send to interface % how much file is downloaded. When I go back to settings and go again to update activity, the interface still remeber previous % and still download from  previous task.
This is how I execute  task.

```
fun startUpdate( listener: ApplicationUpdaterResponder) {
        coroutine.launch {
            try {
                updater.tryUpdate(listener, AppVariant.Companion)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                setMessage(e.message.toString())
                Log.i(TAG, e.printStackTrace().toString())
            }
        }
    }
```

I trying to stop this task by close coroutine but it dont work

```
    fun stopJob() {
        updater.stopUpdate()
        coroutine.cancel("Przerwano")
    }
```

This is how look tryUpdate

```
class DownloadAPK(val context: Context): AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {
 override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String?): String {
//here fille download and update listener(interface)
//listener.setPercent((progress*100)/total)
}
```

Result must be this : Like user go  out from update activity, the task stops, and if user go again to update it should start everything from zero.

Now its still remember previous task and two values are send to interface old and new.

I try to execute task with CoroutineScope  and try cancel functionbut its dont work.
I also try to define DownloadAPK(val context: Context) as variable and then on  variable use .cancel(true) but  it still dont work

Edit//
I  tried zahid proposition but this still dont work

```
private var job : Job?  = null
    fun startUpdate(context: Context, listener: ApplicationUpdaterResponder) {
        job = viewModelScope.launch(IO) {
            try {
                val updater = ApplicationUpdater(context)
                updater.tryUpdate(listener, AppVariant.Companion.TransportFP4)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e)
                setMessage(e.message.toString())
            }
        }

    }
    fun stopJob() {
        job!!.cancel()
    }
```

This is how it look on image: in viewModel I  start coroutineScope and then  it start AsyncTask
[This is how it look on image: in viewModel I  start coroutineScope and then  it start AsyncTask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NCjr.png)

Comment: If you are calling from the ViewModel, can you try using `viewModelScope.launch`?

Comment: @akubi thanks for comment, I already tried this solution but it still didn't work

Comment: Are you saying you want to keep your AsyncTask and manage it from a coroutine? That's going to be exceedingly complicated to get working correctly with cancellation. Why not replace the AsyncTask with a coroutine? By the way, you missed adding your code for `tryUpdate()`.

Comment: @Tenfour04 hey, thanks for respond,  so you suggest  to change whole AsyncTask  to coroutine and this should work? `tryUpdate()` function is not important

Comment: Yes, if you want to work with coroutines, I would get rid of the AsyncTask. `tryUpdate()` is important because we would need to see it to know how to adapt it to something that can cooperate with cancellation. Cancelling a coroutine cannot interrupt blocking functions, and asynchronous tasks like AsyncTask would have to be manually cancelled when the coroutine is cancelled.

Comment: @Tenfour04  thanks, I follow your  advice and chagne AsyncTask to coroutine works.

Answer (score 0):

You can create co-routine this way and than close it.

```
val job= CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch { 
        //write your code here
    }
    //write your code here
    job.cancel()
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment i already tried take val coroutine = CoroutineScope(Dispatcher.IO) and then coroutine.cancel() as in my code above, but I tried your code like this: look at edit post